# Angular $locationProvider.html5Mode with $window variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently run into problems with google indexing because of angular routing. So, the solution that I found was using $locationProvider.html5Mode.

But now I created another problem, the $window variables loose their value when the user navigates between the same page application routes.

There is any way that I can keep the value of an $window variable between controllers using $locationProvider.html5Mode set to true? (In the same page app).

Comment: which are you talking about? there is `$location` which wraps that

Comment: Which? I'm talking about the ngRoute... AngularJS + ngRoute with $locationProvider.html5Mode set to true + $window variables working.

Comment: which `$window` variables?

Comment: I think he is talking about global variables, and have an issue with refreshes

Comment: That's right. The ones I create $window.myVar = 1...

Comment: There is any way to stop the page refresh when the request is within the same base (page)?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing:

```
window.location.href = "/base/some_route/";
```

turns out I should be doing:

```
$location.path("/someroute");
```

Hope that this will save time to someone.